# split csv files without keeping the original csv

Tags: linux, awk, sed, csv

I have a large CSV file and want to split it into small chunks. I know that I can split the CSV file using

`split -l 1000000 file.csv new`

which results in a part having lines of 1000000.But the problem is it splits but also the original one exists. Since I do not have much space in my disk is there any way to split the CSV without keeping the original one? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, assuming GNU `stat(1)` and GNU `truncate(1)`:

```bash
#! /bin/sh

lines=1000000

size=$( wc -l "$1" | awk '{print $1}' )
tail=$(( size % lines ))
count=$(( size / lines ))

if [ $tail -ne 0 ]; then
    let count++
fi           

while [ $count -gt 0 ]; do
    start=$(( (count - 1) * lines + 1 ))
    fn=$( printf '%s_%05d' "$1" $count )
    sed -n $start,\$p <"$1" >"$fn"
    size_last=$( stat -c %s "$fn" )
    truncate -s -$size_last "$1"
    let count--
done
```

Without GNU `coreutils`, the same thing could be done in Perl.

The original file gets lost in the process, so it's probably wise to test the above against a few smaller files first, with `lines` set to, say, 100.

Answer (score 1):

If the memory on your system is large enough to hold the whole `csv` file, you could try this **very dangerous** way of putting the file into a temporary file system (i.e. a virtual hard drive in your RAM) and then start splitting it from there onto the hard drive.

Note that when the PC is powered down while the file is in this `tmpfs` the **data will be lost**! This is very, very prone to making you unhappy.

Usually `/dev/shm` should be present already, double check if `mount | grep shm` lists a `tmpfs` as mounted on `/dev/shm`, then:

```
mv file /dev/shm
split -l 1000000 /dev/shm/file /path/to/split/directory/
```

I don't know how much excess memory you'll need apart from the file size, as I am not familiar with `split`'s memory usage, but it would be at least the one million lines you are splitting, I assume.

Again **be prepared for data loss** on a simple power outage or anything unexpected.

PS: Maybe you have a USB flash drive at hand to use as your temporary file system - less dangerous, but slower.

Answer (score -1):

If it's OK to reverse the order of the CSV fields, you could try something along the following lines:

```
SIZ=$(stat -c %s input)
tac input |\
(
  IFS=""
  while read -r LINE
  do
    ADJ=${#LINE}
    SIZ=$(( (SIZ-ADJ-1) ))
    truncate -s $SIZ input
    echo "$LINE"
  done
) |\
split -l 10 - output
```

It will also take longer to run than a plain `split` command, but maybe not very much longer.

It does conserve disk space, allowing it to be run even if the starting file takes up nearly 100% of available disk space.

You will want to change the file names and increase the `-l 10` argument to `split`. I posted it the way I tested it, on a file with far fewer than a million lines.

Comment: That's great, until you realize that `tac`, depending on implementation, might also create a temp file of a size comparable to the initial one.  Why do you bother with `tac` to begin with, all you need is the start of each 1 mil. lines anyway.

Comment: @SatoKatsura There is no conceivable reason for `tac` to create a temp file of a size comparable to the initial one. The intermediate storage needed to implement `tac` is the length of the longest line only.

Comment: How about input not being seek-able? :)